# How to help a 7 year old understand how much sleep he needs?

Tags: bedtime

My son is now writing a timetable for himself which is fantastic. His mother was never keen because she'd have to keep to it too. His mother is finally starting to try to set a bedtime but still fails since is sleepy every morning before school- constantly running to lie down after breakfast and before leaving in walking to school group. H He is a screen head and Pokemon nut and just before sleeping he wants to write or make origami. I suspect he has some disorder but his mother is unwilling to pursue it so in mean time we should try to have a good sleep schedule. so We have one room for him and mother and one room for me.  How to help him understand how much sleep he needs?

Comment: How much sleep is he getting at night? Frequently kids who are getting enough sleep will still be sleepy in the morning/need naps in the afternoon. You say he's a screenhead, is there a time in the evening where he's not allowed screens anymore? That can help people fall asleep earlier. Are you and his mother in the same house, or does he split time between the two of you? Does his mother share the same bedtime or does she wake him up when she goes to bed later?

Comment: We live together. Mother has the same bedtime as they sleep together. Generally he doesn't nap unless you count less than a minute. He occasionally collapses into bed after coming home from afterschool English school (he goes to a public Japanese elementary school) at 6:15 pm. Then he sleeps until we wake him up for dinner.

Comment: What is that bedtime? If he's sleeping from 6:15 until dinner, it could be he's not falling asleep because he had such a late nap. I know if I sleep after 3pm, I find it much harder to fall asleep at bedtime.

Comment: And also, what time does he have to be up and ready for school?

Comment: Ready to leave at 7;30 am. Sleeping until dinner is rare. Bedtime is 10 pm but drinks and insisting on drawing and mummy special play can push it back. The question is how to get him to realize what time he should be asleep? His personal timetable has him awake at 6 am.

Comment: 10pm-6am is only 8 hours of sleep. 7-year-olds need a lot more than that; according to the [NHS](https://www.wsh.nhs.uk/CMS-Documents/Patient-leaflets/PaediatricDepartment/6339-1-Sleep-a-guide-for-school-age-children.pdf) they need 10-11 hours of sleep. You can just tell the child exactly that: sleeping from 10 t 6 is only 8 hours, they *need* to have at least 10, so they need to sleep at 8 instead of 10. He doesn't need to "understand" how much sleep he needs, he can just *know* "at least 10 hours" and you can help him with the math.